# How can I pass tailwind classes to fontawesome in Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I am using the [Angular FontAwesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome) package to handle icons in my project.

Following the docs, I am able to render my icon like this from my component:

```
...
import { faSignOut } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostBinding('class') classes = 'h-full';

    faSignOut = faSignOut;
    
    ...
}
```

My template looks like this:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSignOut" class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-linear group-hover:text-white"></fa-icon>
```

The icon is rendered, but the tailwind classes are placed on the `<fa-icon>`.

I can manually code the items, but I would like to pass the names of the icon from my component to my template from a loop.

How can I pass the `h-6 w-6` class from the `<fa-icon>` to the generated svg?

For example:

```
<fa-icon class="ng-fa-icon">
    <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-300 transition duration-75 ease-linear group-hover:text-white">...</svg>
</fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom classes from `[classes]` property binding in array format. [Docs Reference](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/5581dee5fc060ea5383e5a66bc3f3504bf491446/docs/usage/features.md#custom-classes)

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSignOut" [classes]="['h-6', 'w-6']">
</fa-icon>
```

Comment: THIS WORKED! Thank you so much! I saw that in the docs, but I didn't think that by binding to them it would pass them down to the svg. Thank you again for your time & suggestion!